# communicating between two controller in angularjs using factory

Tags: angularjs

I have created a plunker that communicates between two different controller in nested views using factory. Below is the url of plunker. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/fWA2Xugjbkf3QvHKfTa0?p=preview . 
Here is the factory.

```
routerApp.factory("widgetService",function($state){
    var callbackFunctions=[];
    var counter=0;

    var addWidget=function(name){
        callbackFunctions[0](name);
    }

    var addCallback=function(callback){
        if (callbackFunctions.length===0) {
            callbackFunctions.push(callback);
        }
    }
    return{
        addCallback: addCallback,
        addWidget: addWidget
    }
})
```

Scenario 1: 
1. Click on "List" menu under the home page.
2. Click on "verify" button. notice the change in highlighted area with yellow. Text changes from "Chandan" to "singh1".
3. Click again on verify button.  Text changes from "singh1" to "singh2". So i am able to communicate between two controller in this.

Scenario 2: 
1. Repeat the scenario 1 till step 2.
2. Click on "PARAGRAPH" menu under home page. 
3. Click on "List" menu under home page. Click verify button. The text wont change. It will remain "chandan".
 Communication is not working as we change the state.

Also i have observed  that the model is changing but same is not getting reflected in view. Moreover if we bind the view to rootscope, view is getting updated.
Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you switch between list and paragraph states, your list controller is destroyed (and recreated next time you go to list). So when it is recreated it gets a new scope.

The callbackFunction that is registered in your service, refers to the `changeMyName()` function on the **old** controller scope, so whenever you call `addWidget()` in your service, you're actually calling the callback in your old scope.

To make this work as expected (at least in your sample code here), you would have to change your service to allow changing the old callback in the `addCallback()`-function. Something like this:

```
var addCallback=function(callback){
    callbackFunctions[0] = callback;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. If you've found it helpful please consider up-voting and marking it as answered.

Comment: can you let me know the reason , changeMyName() function is called when  it is registered on old controller scope. I have voted it up

Comment: The function still exists, but the controller that registered the function is "destroyed" (ie. no longer referenced by Angular). Thus you can still call the function, since it's still referenced by your service.